# Implementation of push notification using oracle maf

Tags: oracle-maf

Iam able to register using device token.but I didn't receive message from my server.I have registered my project with GCM and got project Id ,server key.

enter code here

```
public void onMessage(Event event) {
    String msg;
    msg = event.getPayload();
    System.out.println("#### Message from the Server :" + msg);
    String one="";
    AdfmfContainerUtilities.invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getFeatureId(), "usercheck", new Object[]{msg});
    // Parse the payload of the push notification
    HashMap payload = null;
    String pushMsg = "No message received";
    try
    {
      payload = (HashMap)JSONBeanSerializationHelper.fromJSON(HashMap.class, msg);
      pushMsg = (String)payload.get("alert");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Write the push message to app scope to display to the user        
    AdfmfJavaUtilities.setELValue("#{applicationScope.pushMessage}", pushMsg);
}

public void onError(AdfException adfException) {
    System.out.println("#### Error: " + adfException.toString());
    // Write the error into app scope        
    AdfmfJavaUtilities.setELValue("#{applicationScope.errorMessage}", adfException.toString());

}

public void onOpen(String token) {
    System.out.println("#### Registration token:" + token);
    // Clear error in app scope
    AdfmfJavaUtilities.setELValue("#{applicationScope.errorMessage}", null);

    // Write the token into app scope
    AdfmfJavaUtilities.setELValue("#{applicationScope.deviceToken}", token);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please tell me from where you call these onOpen , onError methods??

Comment: From LifeCycleListenerImpl.java                                                                                public void start()
    {
        EventSource evtSource = EventSourceFactory.getEventSource(EventSourceFactory.NATIVE_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_REMOTE_EVENT_SOURCE_NAME);
        evtSource.addListener(new NativePushNotificationListener());
    }

Comment: The above code snippet is from NativePushNotificationListener?

Comment: yes ...But when I sent msg from server I receive a warning ..

Comment: what message did you get ? Please provide the full information

Comment: FatalError:Badcertificate -A Corrupted or unuseable Certificate was received I received Warning

Comment: So the problem is with your p12 certificate. you have to use production p12 without encryption. then your problem will be solved.

Comment: Is P12 certificate is needed for android applications??

Comment: No... It is for iOS apps

Answer (score 0):

I think [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/how_to_implement_push_notifications) will help you. I was able to get them done for GCM but not for APN yet.

For registering with Google Cloud Messaging, go to [this link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start), then click on "Get configuration" button.

In the server application, set your device token and sender id properly. The message is sent using these.

Answer (score 0):

Since you got the `deviceId`  from the server then i think the issue is not with the code. Did you enable `PushPlugin` in `maf-application.xml` ?

Comment: Could you please tell me whether onMessage() calls or not?

Comment: I am not sure of it... I think It is not called.

Comment: then try it using System.out.prinln() , so that you can check whether the method is called or not